# Which file contains the Elisp code which loads the installed packages?

Tags: emacs

I have installed some Emacs packages such as the starter-kit using `M-x package-install`. Both of my ~/.emacs and ~/.emacs.d/init.el files are empty but the installed packages still get loaded.

I wonder how Emacs loads it's installed packages? Where the code that loads the install packages resides?

I am using the pre-compiled Emacs24.BZR.106722.Win32 version.

Comment: In the `*scratch*` buffer, what do `user-init-file` `C-j` and `(expand-file-name user-emacs-directory)` `C-j` report? (or rather, are they the same as you had thought?)

Comment: user-init-file C-j reports  "c:/Documents and Settings/my_name/.emacs" ; (expand-file-name user-emacs-directory) C-j reports "c:/Documents and Settings/my_name/.emacs.d/"

Comment: sorry,I mean my ~/.emacs.d/init.el is empty,the ~/.emacs.d directory is not empty.I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory, which is where package.el (a.k.a. ELPA for Emacs Lisp Package Archive) stores its data.

Failing that,
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `package-user-dir` <kbd>RET</kbd>

**Edit**:

From the NEWS file (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

> ** An Emacs Lisp package manager is now included.
>   This is a convenient way to download and install additional packages,
>   from a package repository at http://elpa.gnu.org.
>
> *** `M-x list-packages` shows a list of packages, which can be
>   selected for installation.
>
> *** New command ``describe-package`', bound to ``C-h P`'.
>
> *** By default, all installed packages are loaded automatically when
>   Emacs starts up.  To disable this, set ``package-enable-at-startup`' to
>   `nil`.  To specify the packages to load, customize ``package-load-list`'.

Comment: I found there is a `package-initialize` function which loads all the installed packages in the package.el file but both of my ~/.emacs and ~/.emacs.d/init.el do not invoke it. Where it gets invoked?

Comment: package.el (the library, not the file in your elpa directory) is a part of Emacs 24, and is used automatically. `M-x find-library RET package RET`. See edit to answer for the relevant NEWS entry.